# How to tell thunderbird to use doc viewer for pdf

Tags: pdf, thunderbird, evince

In Thunderbird settings I can tell it to use a specific program to open all pdf documents.  I want to use the document viewer utility (evince) but I don't know how to indicate that to Thunderbird.  If I try to browse (from within Thunderbird) to /usr/bin, which is where the most of the programs seem to be, "permission denied".  If I scan through /user/bin using Nautilus, I can't find any program named 'evince' or 'document viewer' anyway.  So where is evince and how do I tell Thunderbird to use it?

Comment: Why not have evince default to open all PDF docs?

Comment: You're using snap version of thunderbird, which is sandboxed. You could use workarounds I've included in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workarounds:

- The simplest solution is to install thunderbird from official ubuntu repositories: `sudo apt install thunderbird`. Because of Thunderbird installed through `snap` could not see a list of installed apps.
- The second option is to install evince using snap: `sudo snap install evince`. It will be available for opening pdf documents in thunderbird, installed through snap.

Make evince your default document viewer by right mouse button clicking on some.pdf file and set **Document Viewer** in **Open With** tab as your Default Application for this type of files:

[image: default app for pdf docs]

In case of opening pdf files in Thunderbird it will be displayed as a default app for this type of files:

[image: default pdf app]

Make sure **Evince** is installed:

```
$ whereis evince
evince: /usr/bin/evince /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/evince /usr/lib/evince /usr/share/evince
```

Also, make sure, its `.desktop` files are present in `/usr/share/applications`:

```
$ ls -ailh /usr/share/applications/*Evin*
1707752 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,3K жов  8 02:28 /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop
1707751 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  401 жов  8 02:28 /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince-previewer.desktop
```

So it could be visible in the main menu and from **Open With** properties tab.

If you want to access a binary without going to `/usr/bin` where you do not have access from your user workspace, then create a symlink to it in your `/home/user/bin/` folder:

```
mkdir ~/bin && ln -s /usr/bin/evince-previewer /home/user/bin/
```

Also, check permissions by:

```
ls -ailh /usr/ | grep bin
1441794 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  72K бер  6 16:34 bin
```

You should have execution access marked as `x` in that output for others.

Comment: Evince was already the default if I right-clicked a pdf.  However, the response to ls -ailh /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evin* is :No such file or directory.  There are other org.gnome files for other apps but not evince.  Evince was installed with ubuntu, basic installation from disc.  How can this be corrected?

Comment: In /usr/share/applications, evince.desktop and evince-preview.desktop are there but not org.gnome.evince.desktop, etc.

Comment: The dir already exists and I have the execute permissions.

Comment: Thunderbird doesn't see any default app to open a PDF and it doesn't see any apps in Browse except those directly related to Thunderbird itself.  For instance I have LibreOffice which could open a pdf in writer but that isn't seen by Thunderbird.  Thunderbird is the only app I'm using that doesn't see other document apps.  I probably couldn't open a spreadsheet from Thunderbird because it wouldn't see LibreOffice calc.  Could this be something in the Thunderbird profile?

Comment: The symlink already existed.  mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/sharon/bin’: File exists

Comment: What does `ps aux | grep thunderbird` show?

Comment: sharon   15808  2.1  7.3 2893036 290904 tty2   Sl+  11:13   2:08 /snap/thunderbird/48/thunderbird-bin
sharon   17261  0.0  0.0  21532  1064 pts/0    S+   12:53   0:00 grep --color=auto thunderbird

Comment: First many thanks for the help.  I prefer having TB able to access any program that could open an attachment, so just putting evince in snap won't solve the problem entirely.  If I install TB using apt, what do I do with the one in snap?  I'm aware that I want to copy my current profile somewhere before I start this process.  I assume that regardless where TB is installed, the profile I use will still be in my snap directory?

Comment: I think, you could ask a new question concerning **How to migrate Thunderbird profile from snap version to apt version** or whatever. But answer to your question is *no*. TB from apt uses different profile.